# Update only two columns from one CSV file to another CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, file-handling

I have two files, the first one is called first.csv, and looks like this:

```
header1,header2
1,a
2,b
```

The second file is called second.csv, and looks like this:

```
header1,header2,header3,header4,header5
1,a,m,n,o
2,b,p,q,r
```

My Goal is to append a new row in **second.csv** if any new row added in **first.csv**

And I need a result like:

**first.csv**

```
header1,header2
1,a
2,b
3,c
```

then

**second.csv**

```
header1,header2,header3,header4,header5
1,a,m,n,o
2,b,p,q,r
3,c,-,-,-,-
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try using joins in pandas?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of that. Can you write snippet for that? @dper

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this. Stack Overflow is not the place to have others write all your code for you, particularly when there is no evidence of even the tiniest amount of research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the joins :

```
pd.merge(first, second, how='left', on=None, left_on=None, right_on=None,
         left_index=False, right_index=False, sort=True,
         suffixes=('_x', '_y'), copy=True, indicator=False,
         validate=None)
```

This might be more intuitive if you go through this post, It might provide you a clear idea of how to actually perform the joins ...

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html